# Bokeh: remove registered on_change callback?

Tags: bokeh

For a code like the following:

```
def foo(attr, old, new):
  print "Replacing value %s with %s" % (old, new)

selector = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["a", "b"], active=0)
selector.on_change("active", foo)
```

what is the proper way to remove the callback afterwards (i.e. detach foo from selector)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each model has `remove_on_change` method:

```
def foo(attr, old, new):
    ...
    selector.remove_on_change('active', foo)
```

Comment: A note for this answer: If you use `selector.on_click(foo)`, there is no `selector.remove_on_click(foo)` and `selector.remove_on_change('active', foo)` will not work.

Comment: You can use `selector.remove_on_change('active', foo)` anywhere ,not necessarily inside `foo` callback.